# Wireless Time Synchronization IC

Tags: synchronization

In my application I need a clock that is synchronized across several devices. (A detailed description of my system is given in an [earlier](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/351198/synchronize-clocks) question)

It appears achieving precision timing at a software level is not practical, therefore I am looking for a complete hardware solution. In this case I am looking for some sort of hardware that emits a clock that is completely synchronized across several nodes over the air.

Therefore, Are there low cost, short range (up to 20-30 meters) ICs that emit a clock synchronized across several wireless nodes? I cannot use GPS since my system will work mostly indoors.

Comment: @Harry Svensson It appears you guys didn't read the questions well. I am the author of both. This solution looks for a wireless synchronization mechanism. The earlier one looks for a system level solution. Their intent is same but the the real questions are completely different.

Comment: Either way, I'm sorry to inform that product recommendation questions are off-topic.

Comment: @WesleyLee I would have agreed if I was asking a vs. b but I am not even sure it exists. You guys are real sticklers for rules which sometimes ruins the fun of this site.

Comment: Hmm, I would suggest explicitly including the possibility of hardware based solutions on your original question, so people can recommend such IC if it exists.

Comment: @WesleyLee the question clearly states that "hardware solution"

Comment: After some researh I come across solutions people can leverage BLE for this purpose and achieve remarkable resolutions (sub microsecond). Here is a relevant blog post. https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/blogs/978/wireless-timer-synchronization-among-nrf5-devices/

Comment: Nice find! You can answer your own question if this turns out to be a viable solution.